# How to make sense of DICT data in CFF font format

Tags: pdf, fonts

### Problem

I'm trying to parse a OTF/CFF font and is struggling with top DICT part, more specifically the top DICT data part.

### CFF File

The beginning of CFF table[image] looks like this in hex editor:

The top DICT starts from the second line from offset 0xC2 with 00 01 "top DICT INDEX count", 01 "top DICT INDEX offsetsize", 01 77 "top DICT INDEX offsets".

The large yellow section is the data part for the DICT, but I simply cannot make sense of it. I referenced: https://typekit.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/5176.cff.pdf
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/T1_SPEC.pdf

### Things I tried

1. Since top DICT starts with version, Notice, Copyright which are SID, so I tried to look up the offsetted strings but they were way off the strings.
2. I tried to encode them using Table 3 in page 10 of the CFF reference pdf, essentially taking two bytes, b0, b1, and calculating the value, but the values seemed unrelated.

### Further Information

It seems I'm having difficulty understanding Table 3 and Table 4. So the DICT data is supposed to be 1 or 2 byte operators and variable sized operands, and these are concatenated throughout the data? Some examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the encoding procedure. You need to start from the beginning, and based on the first byte, need to find which encoding it uses, integer encodings, real encoding, or instructions etc.
Btw, this font has CIDFont Operator Extensions eg  F8 1B F8 1C 8D 0C 1E meaning it is a CID font. So it doesn't have encoding offset, don't waste time like me trying to find one!

[image]